# Gradle + Artifactory plugin: Trying to publish the resolved dependency version

Tags: gradle, artifactory

In a gradle project, I have my dependencies set as:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.our_organization.lib', name: 'Libraries', version: '5.+'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
}
```

which uses the latest released version of Libraries, and works perfectly.

I then release my built jar to Artifactory via:

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = artifactory_contextUrl
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = publicationRepoKey
            username = artifactory_user
            password = artifactory_password
            maven = true
        }
    }
}
```

which for the most part works fine.

However, when I go to artifactory and get the xml for any given version, it's dependencies are listed as

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency org="com.our_organization.lib" name="Libraries" rev="5.+" />
  <dependency org="commons.io" name="commons.io" rev="2.4" />
</dependencies>
```

which means I am unable to link my version to the specific Libraries version that was used for its build.

What I'd like to do is have the dependency version given to artifactory be the specific resolved version that is used in the build.

I've scoped a couple of things, all very hacky, and feel there has to be a better way.

Here's what I've thought of / tried:

1. Resolving the dependency myself and setting the specific version in the gradle dependency dsl, so to gradle it looks like a specific version. Using ivy to get the resolved version of a dependency of proving to be harder that it should.
2. Mucking the xml after its written but before it's sent to artifactory. This is just bad on so many levels and prone to breaking in the future.
3. Using a seperate gradle project to determine the resolved version and write that to a properties file which is then used similarly to #1. This feels like overkill.

Overall, this seems like a simple for which, for the life of me, I can't find an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what Gradle will do with it in pom.xml, but you might try using the [Artifactory's functionality to retrieving the latest version](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact), instead of Gradle's one.

Answer (score 0):

The post

[In Gradle, how can I generate a POM file with dynamic dependencies resolved to the actual version used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959558/in-gradle-how-can-i-generate-a-pom-file-with-dynamic-dependencies-resolved-to-t/32353697#32353697)

exactly solves this problem. But you have to use the maven-publish Plugin instead of the Artifactory Plugin.