# In Gradle, how can I generate a POM file with dynamic dependencies resolved to the actual version used?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, gradle, pom.xml

In Gradle, how can I generate a POM file with dynamic dependencies resolved to the actual version used?

```
dependencies {
    testCompile(group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+')
}
```

This is generated from the dependency above.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.+</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I want to have the `+` resolved to an accrual version like below.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The Gradle guide chapter on [Maven Publishing](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) talks about doing this, but does not mention how.

> With this hook, you can modify any aspect of the POM. For example, you could replace the version range for a dependency with the actual version used to produce the build.

### Solution

Using the information in Peter Niederwieser's answer, I created a task that reads a POM that contains dynamic dependencies and overwrites it with a new pom that has the dependencies resolved.

```
/**
 * Reads and Overwrites POM file resolving dynamic dependencies
 */
task cleanPom(dependsOn: writeNewPom) << {
    // Get existing pom file
    Node xml = new XmlParser().parse(pomFileLocation)

    // Generate map of resolved versions
    Map resolvedVersionMap = new HashMap()
    Set<ResolvedArtifact> resolvedArtifacts = configurations.compile.getResolvedConfiguration().getResolvedArtifacts()
    resolvedArtifacts.addAll(configurations.testCompile.getResolvedConfiguration().getResolvedArtifacts())
    resolvedArtifacts.each {
        resolvedVersionMap.put(it.getName(), it.getModuleVersion().getId().getVersion())
    }

    // Update dependencies with resolved versions
    xml.dependencies.first().each {
        Node artifactId = it.get("artifactId").first()
        def artifactName = artifactId.value().first()
        def artifactVersion = resolvedVersionMap.get(artifactName)

        Node version = it.get("version").first()
        version.value = artifactVersion
    }

    // Overwrite existing pom file
    new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(pomFileLocation))).print(xml)
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you use the `pom.withXml()` hook shown in the sample I linked to?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I am currently using the old 'maven' plugin to create a POM file and this code will modify the POM I am already creating. I assume that `pom.withXml()` is part of the new *incubating* 'maven-publish' plugin.

Comment: There is a similar hook (and sample) for the old plugin. With the old plugin there is even a simpler solution, because it allows to manipulate the POM on an object level (demonstrated in the same sample).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Thanks, I will have to revisit and update this when I have time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will require some effort to code this up. The two main parts are:

- Querying resolved versions using the `Configuration#getIncoming` or `Configuration#getResolvedConfiguration` API
- Manipulating the POM using Groovy's `XMlParser` API (assuming the new `maven-publish` plugin is used)

Information about the `Configuration` API can be found in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html), which further links into the Javadoc.
The full Gradle distribution contains a [tiny sample](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/maven-publish/pomCustomization/build.gradle) that demonstrates POM manipulation. Information about `XmlParser` can be found in the Groovy docs.

Answer (score 3):

The solution with the `pom.withXml()` suggested by Peter looks like this:

```
publishing {
  publications {
    mavenCustom(MavenPublication) {
        from components.java
            pom.withXml {
                // Generate map of resolved versions
                Map resolvedVersionMap = [:]
                Set<ResolvedArtifact> resolvedArtifacts = configurations.compile.getResolvedConfiguration().getResolvedArtifacts()
                resolvedArtifacts.addAll(configurations.testCompile.getResolvedConfiguration().getResolvedArtifacts())
                resolvedArtifacts.each {
                    ModuleVersionIdentifier mvi = it.getModuleVersion().getId();
                    resolvedVersionMap.put("${mvi.getGroup()}:${mvi.getName()}", mvi.getVersion())
                }

              // Update dependencies with resolved versions
              def hasDependencies = !asNode().dependencies.isEmpty()
              if (hasDependencies) {
                  asNode().dependencies.first().each {
                      def groupId = it.get("groupId").first().value().first()
                      def artifactId = it.get("artifactId").first().value().first()
                      it.get("version").first().value = resolvedVersionMap.get("${groupId}:${artifactId}")
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this work with Android projects? I am receiving error "Error:Could not get unknown property 'java' for SoftwareComponentInternal set." on the line from components.java. 

Previously I was using mavenDeployer: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html. How can I use these together?

Comment: I've never worked with Android before, but did you apply the java-plugin in the gradle file?

Answer (score 2):

I've taken a stab at integrating this into a plugin that can be applied, the specific code is available here: https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-publishing-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/nebula/plugin/publishing/maven/ResolvedMavenPlugin.groovy

And it can be included via jcenter() via 'com.netflix.nebula:nebula-publishing-plugin:1.9.1'.

Answer (score 1):

As of Gradle 5.2, the `versionMapping` block of MavenPublication can be used to achieve this:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'my.group'
            artifactId 'my-artifact'
            from components.java

            versionMapping {
                allVariants {
                    fromResolutionResult()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/5.2/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:resolved_dependencies