# How can get both rev and revConstraint for dynamic dependency in published ivy.xml of Gradle build

Tags: gradle

I have a question about Ivy publishing in Gradle.

From Ivy, I expect that if I publish an artifact with for example this dependency:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.ant" name="ant" rev="1+"/>
```

My published ivy.xml gets both the fixed and the dynamic version:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.ant" name="ant" rev="1.9.6" revConstraint="1+"/>
```

I want that also in Gradle. I have Gradle 2.10.

Here is my Gradle project:

```
apply plugin: "java"

group = 'org.wibble'
version = "1.2.3"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.apache.ant', name: 'ant', version: '1+' // resolves to version 1.9.6 at the time of writing
}

uploadArchives.repositories {
  ivy { name "testrepo"; url "$buildDir/testrepo" }
}
```

If I run `gradle uploadArchives` the resulting ivy.xml just has this:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.ant" name="ant" rev="1+" conf="compile-&gt;default"/>
```

In the [source code of Gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/6277a4dc70fbeea83c111e75c95ba851d1e56ffc/subprojects/dependency-management/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/ivyservice/IvyXmlModuleDescriptorWriter.java#L121) I do see that there is a facility for writing both rev and revConstraint:

```
if (!dep.getDynamicConstraintDependencyRevisionId().equals(dependencyRevisionId)) {
    <...>
    writer.attribute("revConstraint", dep.getDynamicConstraintDependencyRevisionId().getRevision());
}
```

With debugging I also see that this code is hit, but, in my case both getDynamicConstraintDependencyRevisionId and dependencyRevisionId give '1+' at this point, and the 1.9.6 version is forgotten at this point.

What can I do to get the dependency version recorded in the published ivy.xml, just like in Ivy?

Comment: Same problem with the newer `ivy-publish` plugin, the resolved version is dropped before writing `ivy.xml`

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959558/in-gradle-how-can-i-generate-a-pom-file-with-dynamic-dependencies-resolved-to-t/21241393#21241393) are some answers that try to hack the resolved version into a generated maven `pom.xml`, You could do something similar to modify `ivy.xml` as well.

Comment: let me know if you want me to take a stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is of any help anymore. But I had to address a similar issue recently, and came up with the following approach. Hope it can help some one else looking for a solution. I derived to this answer based on clues from RaGe's [Pom solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959558/in-gradle-how-can-i-generate-a-pom-file-with-dynamic-dependencies-resolved-to-t/21241393#21241393) and [gradle forum solution](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/getting-version-of-a-dependency-resolved-with-resolutionstrategy/4228/2).

The reason I had to implement this was, the ivy being published by gradle had rev, but not revConstraint attribute. But rev always said "latest.release" which is what is used for our internal libraries. So I had to manually put the rev to actual revision and the revConstraint to latest.release.

```
publishing {
publications {
    ivyJava(IvyPublication) {            
        from components.java
        configurations.create('sources')
        artifact(sourceJar) {
            type "source"
            conf "sources"
            classifier "sources"
        }
        configurations.create('javadoc')
        artifact(javadocJar) {
            type "javadoc"
            conf "javadoc"
            classifier "javadoc"
        }
        descriptor {
            withXml {
                if (project.configurations.findByName("runtime") != null) {
                    Map resolvedVersionMap = [:]
                    Configuration runtimeConfiguration = project.configurations.getByName('runtime')
                    ResolutionResult resolution = runtimeConfiguration.incoming.resolutionResult
                    resolution.getAllComponents().each { ResolvedComponentResult versionResult ->
                        resolvedVersionMap.put("${versionResult.moduleVersion.group}:" +
                                ":${versionResult.moduleVersion.name}", versionResult.moduleVersion.version)
                    }

                    asNode().dependencies.dependency.each { dep ->
                        if ("latest.release".equalsIgnoreCase(dep.@rev) || "latest.integration".equalsIgnoreCase(dep.@rev)
                                || "latest.snapshot".equalsIgnoreCase(dep.@rev)) {
                            dep.@revConstraint = dep.@rev
                            dep.@rev = resolvedVersionMap.get("${dep.@org}:" +
                                    ":${dep.@name}")
                            dep.@changing = "true"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}